# direct link to download from datafile.com

Tags: download, data-files

i want to download a file from datafile.com
can someone give me direct download link for download.
it start with n79.datafile.com.html i want this url for my file
here is url of file which i want to download

http://www.datafile.com/d/TVRZek1UVTBNelUF9/HOLLYWOOD%20STRINGS%20DIAMOND%20EDITION%20Full%20Cracked.iso

I have tried generating direct link from many sites but they dont support link for file size above 1 gb and my file size is 3.76 gb. You can also pm me direct link
thanks
please help

Answer (score 0):

Request your link in chatbox at http://downloadfullfree.com/p/ , they give direct download link for big files also, and for free, i regularly get direct links of nitroflare, turbobit, datafile , many other filehosts  from there. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.